# Pig Dump Command to run in silent mode

Tags: apache-pig, dump

Do we have anything to prevent the map-reduce being shown when we use `DUMP` command in PIG. Just wanted to see the output. Anything that could be run in silent mode?

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in the `/conf/pig.properties`

```
$PIG_HOME/conf/pig.properties :
enable:
# log4jconf=./conf/log4j.properties

rename: log4j.properties.template -> log4j.properties

log4j.properties :
set info to error:
log4j.logger.org.apache.pig=info, A
```

May not work with pig version 0.12+.